# c# win application

Tags: c#, winforms

```
int a, b;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = 600;
        this.Height = 436;

        for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
        {
            for (b = 1; b <= 8; b++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Name = (((a - 1) * 8) + b).ToString();
                btn.Width = 50;
                btn.Height = 50;
                btn.Left = (b - 1) * 50;
                btn.Top = (a - 1) * 50;

                if ((a + b) % 2 == 0)
                    btn.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                else
                    btn.BackColor = Color.Black;

                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }
    int i, j,y;
    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            i = int.Parse(btn.Name);
            j = i % 8;
            for (y = 1; y <= 8; j+=8)
            {

            }
        }
```

how can i change other buttons backcolor?

Comment: Might want to reword the question so people know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Anyone have a good link or two about variable scope?  I'm guessing this was cut out of the .cs file...

Comment: @user400065: You seem to already know how to change the back colour of a control through the `Control.BackColor` property. So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear.  What other button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `List<Button>` and add your newly added buttons to this list. Then, you can change any property of button in this list with getting button's index

Comment: bende çeyrek ingilizcemle yarım yamalak bişey sormaya çalışıorum:)

Comment: profilimdeki mail adresimi kullanaraktan banada sorabilirsiniz :)

Comment: çok sağolun mailinizi kaydediyorum bu sorunu hallettim bi dahaki yanlışlarda size danışırım inşallah :)

Comment: tabii ki buyuk bir zevkle yardimci olurum

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep a reference to the other buttons. Preferably: create all buttons, add them to a list. In the eventhandler, iterate that list and set the background color

Answer (score 0):

Use your `this.Controls` reference...not exactly syntactically correct....but you get the idea...

```
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        i = int.Parse(btn.Name);
        j = i % 8;
        for (y = 1; y <= 8; j+=8)
        {
           if(!btn.equals(this.Controls[y]))
              this.Controls[y].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```